# Designation change after resignation

Tags: resignation, india

I've been working in a software firm in India. I got an offer letter from another company for Java developer posting. so I resigned my current job. When I joined in my current job, I was trained in  testing which is my base technology but working in a Java based project. After I resigned, I was assigned to some other project in testing. Due to that my designation is changed. My designation was software analyst when I attended interview and it is Software test analyst now.  I've all the documents including my promotion letter, salary hike letter and pay slips with my designation as software analyst. but in my experience letter and relieving letter, It will be software test analyst as last designation. Will it create any problem while joining with my new employer?

Comment: I would ask that you step back and re-read this question. It does not make much sense as it is. Could you be more specific (name the technologies maybe) so that we can follow the timeline?

Comment: Your new employer probably doesn't care about any changes in job title or responsibilities that happened after they agreed to hire you. Is that what you're worried about?

Comment: Vishal, there is a suggested edit from an anonymous user which makes significant changes to the question. If this is you, then please log in and make the edits using the profile that created the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a title, every company has different titles even for the same position. It all depends on how their internal 'hierarchy' works - it's meaningless otherwise.

Comment: I agree with this. In my experience the type of work you do defines the titles that you can apply to your work. If you are concerned that you can say "hired as an XYZ" and the fact that a reference call might return a slightly different name wouldn't be huge.